# DataList button fires every time the page is refreshed

Tags: c#, webforms, datalist

I have a link button in a DataList in a shopping cart that works fine. Once they have selected the product, if they refresh the page, it will retrigger this button.

```
    <asp:DataList runat="server" ID="rpCategories" RepeatColumns="4" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" OnItemCommand="rpCategories_ItemCommand"
            ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ClientIDMode="Static" ItemStyle-CssClass="bigLink">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="<%=EnrollmentPacksBottomBox %>">
                                <div class="enrollment1ProImage"> 
                                    <img src="../../Common/Images/products/large/<%# Eval("largeImages") %>" width="250" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="enrollment1ProductName">
                                    <%# Eval("productName") %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="enrollment1DescriptionBottom1">
                                    <%# Eval("description") %>
                                </div>
                                <div class="enrollment1Price">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <%# String.Format(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(MyCulture), "{0:c}", Eval("price")) %>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="enrollment1PvSpacer"></div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>PV:
                                                <%# Eval("pv") %>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>  <%-- new amount, and buttons- start--%>
                                    <table class="cartButtonsHolder">
                                        <tr>    
                                            <td>
                                                <div class="">
                                                    <button type="button" style="border: none; background-color: white;">
                                                    <table class="cartButtons">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td rowspan="2">
                                                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="quantityHolder" Text='<%# Eval("quantity") %>' CssClass="QuantityBox"/>
                                                            </td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="upButton" OnClick="AddItem" CssClass="caretButton fas fa-caret-up" Text="" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="downButton" OnClick="SubtractItem" CssClass="caretButton fas fa-caret-down fa-m" Text="" />
                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </table>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" OnClick="SelectPro1Bottom"><div class="enrollment1SelectButton"> Add to Cart</div></asp:LinkButton>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
```

The code behind looks like this:

```
    protected void SelectPro1Bottom(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DAL oDal = new DAL();
        var btn = (LinkButton)sender;
        //var btn = (HtmlButton)sender;
        var item = (DataListItem)btn.NamingContainer;  //RepeaterItem
        int index = item.ItemIndex;
        int quantity = 0;

        GetSelected(index);
        Session["amount"] = 1;
        //pull in the quantity
        Quantities = Session["formatQuantities"] as List<int>;
        List<OrderUserTypeHolder> TempHolder = new List<OrderUserTypeHolder>();
        OrderUserTypeHolder oh = new OrderUserTypeHolder();

        TempHolder = Session["userTypeHolder"] as List<OrderUserTypeHolder>;

        int userType = 0;
        int hasAutoship = 0;
        string country = "";
        userType = TempHolder[0].UserType;
        hasAutoship = TempHolder[0].HasAutoship;
        country = TempHolder[0].Country;

        ProductIdList.Clear();

        using (oDal)
        {
            //dist
            if (userType == 2 && hasAutoship == 1)
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = oDal.ProductsGetAllByDescLengthAutoReader(country);

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    ProductIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rd["productId"]));
                }
            }
            else if (userType == 2)
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = oDal.ProductsGetAllByDescLengthDistReader(country);

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    ProductIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rd["productId"]));
                }
            }
            //pc
            else if (userType == 3)
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = oDal.ProductsGetAllByDescLengthPcReader(country);

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    ProductIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rd["productId"]));
                }
            }
            //retail
            else
            {
                SqlDataReader rd = oDal.ProductsGetAllByDescLengthRetailReader(country);

                while (rd.Read())
                {
                    ProductIdList.Add(Convert.ToInt32(rd["productId"]));
                }
            }
            oDal.Dispose();
        }

        //make sure we don't have an empty array
        if (Quantities.Count > 0)
        {
            quantity = Quantities[index];
        }
        else
        {
            quantity = 1;
        }

        int productId = ProductIdList[index];
        AddItemsToCart(productId, quantity, hasAutoship);
    }
```

I have tried a wide variety of fixes including feeding a value of null to my datasource, changing my view state, and moving it inside !isPostback (the link button won't work). Every time you click the linkbutton it reloads the page (does not go in !isPostback) and refreshing the page has the same effect. Every time the page is rereshed, it will add another of the last item selected to the cart. I have tried everything I could think of and everything I have found online over the past several hours.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well formed question! Better than 99% of the questions here.

Comment: Web Forms? Maintaining an old system? Or moving to [Blazor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazor)?

Comment: Not ASP.NET Web Pages?

Comment: Maintaining an old system. I have downloaded the info on Blazor and plan on checking it out.